# Slider bar in Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, css, slider

I am working on a video-centric application using Ruby 1.9.2 and Rails 3.1. 
I need a slider bar to allow the user to drag and alter the total duration of a video dynamically. I have tried implementing a slider using HTML5, but it does not work in Firefox. I have also tried using Formtastic 2.0.2 - 
http://ballardhack.wordpress.com/2011/02/10/adding-a-custom-jquery-ui-control-to-formtastic-in-ruby-on-rails/
but I get errors with it. Is there any simpler way to do this?

Comment: Rails is almost completely irrelevant. You want an HTML + JS (+CSS) slider.

Answer (score 2):

You can integrate a slider there using jQuery UI's slider:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/

If you're using HAML, you can combine JS and HAML code using the #{} tags.

For example if you're using the :javascript filter and you want to use an @object's name in HAML:

```
-content_for :head do 
  :javascript
    alert(#{@object.name});
```

You MAY need to use the escape_javascript() tag:

```
-content_for :head do 
  :javascript
    alert(#{escape_javascript(@object.name)});
```

I can't recall if you have to escape it or not.